# Flink v6 rest api : how to get all the finished/completed jobs

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In Flink v-1.4, there was a rest api to get all the finished/completed jobs :

/joboverview/completed

As i can see there is no such api in v-1.6, how can i get ONLY the finished/completed jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by configuring and running a [History Server](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/historyserver.html).

In flink-conf.yaml you'll find a section for the History Server. To test this locally I tried these settings:

```
#==============================================================================
# HistoryServer
#==============================================================================

# The HistoryServer is started and stopped via bin/historyserver.sh (start|stop)

# Directory to upload completed jobs to. Add this directory to the list of
# monitored directories of the HistoryServer as well (see below).
jobmanager.archive.fs.dir: file:///tmp/completed-jobs/

# The address under which the web-based HistoryServer listens.
#historyserver.web.address: 0.0.0.0

# The port under which the web-based HistoryServer listens.
#historyserver.web.port: 8082

# Comma separated list of directories to monitor for completed jobs.
historyserver.archive.fs.dir: file:///tmp/completed-jobs/

# Interval in milliseconds for refreshing the monitored directories.
historyserver.archive.fs.refresh-interval: 10000
```

I created `/tmp/completed-jobs`, restarted my cluster, and started the history server, after which I was able to see completed jobs at `http://localhost:8082` (html) and at `http://localhost:8082/jobs/overview` (json).

See the list of [available requests](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/historyserver.html#available-requests) for more info on the API.